# Как удалить src картинки если он содержит "data" между кавычками и заменить data-lazy на src?

Tags: html, python, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть текстовый файл с html кодом, а в частности с тегами img.

Так дело в том, что у большинства img тегов в атрибуте src находится не конкретно ссылка, а "data:image/здесь_рандомные_символы" и в этом же самом теге находится атрибут(data-lazy) с корректной ссылкой.

Вопрос: Как можно на python если src содержит data удалить атрибут и соседний data-lazy заменить на src?

Пример тега:

```
<img src="data:image/ACwAABADs" data-lazy="https://mysite/imgs/img.jpg">
```

Как я хотел что бы оно выглядело в итоге:

```
<img src="https://mysite/imgs/img.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А попробуйте так:

```
import re

text = """\
<img src="data:image/ACwAABADs" data-lazy="https://mysite/imgs/img.jpg">
<img src="data:image/ACwAABADs">
<img src="data:image/ACwAA123" data-lazy="https://mysite/imgs/img123.jpg">
"""

print(re.sub('<img src="data:.+?" data-lazy="(.+?)">', r'<img src="\1">', text))
# <img src="https://mysite/imgs/img.jpg">
# <img src="data:image/ACwAABADs">
# <img src="https://mysite/imgs/img123.jpg">
```

**PS.**

Но я бы рекомендовал вам честно парсером разобрать файл и поменять атрибуты:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
root = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

for img in root.select('img[data-lazy]'):
    img['src'] = img.attrs.pop('data-lazy')

print(root)
# <img src="https://mysite/imgs/img.jpg"/>
# <img src="data:image/ACwAABADs"/>
# <img src="https://mysite/imgs/img123.jpg"/>

with open('1.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(str(root))
```

Comment: У меня просто текстовый файл, а не html так что выбрал вариант с регуляркой, спасибо, работает как надо

Comment: @Кевин, а html сами по себе текстовые файлы :)

Comment: Ну... Так то да)

Но у меня есть только формата txt и xml(между двумя xml тегами находится html код который я и редачу), так что я в целом говорю про текстовый формат

Comment: HTML — **ни разу** не текстовый файл в понимании его обработки. Например, ему чужды понятия *строки*, *номера строки* и тому подобное. В этом ошибка новичков, которые кидаются на HTML всякими `sed`. Вы же сами внизу приводите более интересный вариант (хотя я бы рекомендовал ElementTree).

Comment: @0andriy, под текстовым файлом я подразумевал, что это не бинарный файл. Например, .txt, .html, .xml, .json, .js, .py, .java, .svg -- текстовые файлы, .png, .jpg, .zip, .pdf, .exe -- бинарные файлы. А html, как вы писали, обрабатывается парсером и номера строк не имеют значения, т.к. там данные оперируются тегами и атрибутами

Comment: Off topic: является ли JPEG, преобразованный в base32, текстовым? Вопрос, конечно, риторический. Поэтому такая классификация html даже в этом смысле неочевидна.

Comment: @0andriy, решил погуглить: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Текстовый_файл . Там и про html есть :)

Comment: Читайте английскую вики. Там нет такого прямого упоминания. Но зато есть упоминание MIME type, что как раз и отличает эти форматы: `text/plain` vs. `text/html`. То есть семейство текстовых файлов, с разным возможным содержимым. _"Text file" refers to a type of container, while plain text refers to a type of content._

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, так:

```
import re

a = '<img src="data:image/ACwAABADs" data-lazy="https://mysite/imgs/img.jpg" >'
a = re.sub(r'(src=).*("https)', r'\1\2',a)
print(a)

#<img src="https://mysite/imgs/img.jpg" >
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, так же помогает =)